# Pass parameters to cron job on hybris

Tags: cron, sap-commerce-cloud

```
public class UserRetrievePerformable extends AbstractJobPerformable<UserRetrieveJobModel>
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(UserRetrievePerformable.class);

    @Autowired
    TotalCustomerFacade totalCustomerFacade;



    @Override
    public PerformResult perform(UserRetrieveJobModel userRetrieveJobModel) {
        LOG.info("**********************************");
        LOG.info("Greeting from MyJobPerformable!!!");
        LOG.info("**********************************");

        return new PerformResult(CronJobResult.SUCCESS, CronJobStatus.FINISHED);
    }
```

i want to make this job to get parameter as string.

how can i do this? according to spring docs, it cant be done. But there must be another way?

when i give string from backoffice or somewhere, job will give output that string?

Comment: Check this : https://www.stackextend.com/hybris/everything-about-cronjobs-in-hybris-part-2/

Comment: Firstname in that article is a parameter that being passed to the job

Comment: Where does user give that firstname, i could not see that part sir @MouadELFakir

Comment: In that example the firstname is passed to the job using impex but you can use hmc or backoffice too

Comment: Is it possible adding a input area to get parameter on backoffice? @MouadELFakir

Answer (score 0):

I think you might confuse Job and CronJob. A Job is the task that should be done. A CronJob is a single execution of that task. So if you want to execute a Job, you have to create an instance of a CronJob. You define the task a CronJob should execute by selecting the right Job instance. When this CronJob is started, the perform method of the corresponding AbstractJobPerformable class is called with the CronJob as parameter.

So how do you create parameters for an execution? Create a subtype of the type CronJob and add all your needed parameters as attributes. When you then create the CronJob, set all attributes accordingly. In the perform method you can then access the attributes of that CronJob instance.

You create the CronJob like this:

```
HelloWorldCronJobModel cronJob = modelService.create(HelloWorldCronJobModel.class);
JobModel myJob = cronJobService.getJob("myJob");
cronJob.setJob(myJob);
// Add own attribute to Job
cronJob.setGreetedPerson("John Doe");
modelService.save(cronJob);
cronJobService.performCronJob(cronJob);
```

When your perform method is called, access the attribute:

```
@Override
public PerformResult perform(MyCronJobModel myCronJob) {
    LOG.info("Hello " + myCronJob.getGreetedPerson());

    return new PerformResult(CronJobResult.SUCCESS, CronJobStatus.FINISHED);
}
```

Comment: how can i get parameter from backoffice/cronjobs section?

Comment: Open the CronJob. You should find the attribute in the tab "Administration". Note, that it's also possible to configure the backoffice to display it in a different location.